# Failure to Send Messages as a Guest in Facebook Customer Chat Plugin

Tags: facebook, facebook-chatbot, facebook-send-api

I've been experiencing a few issues with the **Facebook customer chat plugin** on my website, particularly when attempting to send messages as a guest. Here are the issues in detail:

1. Numerous errors are logged in the console and displayed in the network tab.
   [image]
2. When I click "Continue as Guest" for the first time, the chat closes unexpectedly, and I get more error network calls as shown here:
   [image]
3. When I click "Continue as Guest" for the second time, it now opens but a "No internet connection" message appears in the chat plugin window. As shown here:
   [image]

and when I try to send a message it fails as shown below

This functionality has been working smoothly for a long time, and without any recent changes on my end, it ceased to work overnight.

- The chat plugin is embedded on my domain which is whitelisted.
- I'm located in the EU (Could this be related to GDPR restrictions?).
- When logged into the chat plugin, everything works as expected.

Below I will provide a list of sources connected to the issue:

- List item

Answer (score 0):

I'm affected too, guest mode stopped working a few days ago.

I contacted Chatfuel's support. It's a known issue on Facebook's side, there is a bug report on their platform and they should be working on it.

Unfortunately, nothing we can do but wait, apparently. I suggest keeping a close eye on this bug report, to know when it is solved: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/691667882886878/

Let's hope they solve it quickly.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I've subscribed to the bug and mentioned that I'm affected too.

Answer (score 0):

I was affected and It somehow works back today. I do not use chatfuel